# Windows Azure: Open all ports to external world

Tags: routing, vps, azure, port-forwarding

I have tried all options from google. But it seems i'm missing something...
I'm trying to open at least one port...
But it just doesn't open it.

iptables is empty, server is default python -m SimpleHTTPServer.

What i'm missing?

[image]

Comment: Interesting that only 80 port is working. Can't open 8000 port...

Comment: if the service is really running, it's clearly an OS firewall problem. Try nmap localhost to get all the open ports in your server first.  btw is it centos or ubuntu?

Comment: @Somebody - I'm confused about your question, combined with your comment. You're saying you can reach your VM on port 80 from the outside world? In your endpoint table, you don't have port 80 listed anywhere. I only see port 8000  (outside world) open, which is then mapping to internal port 8000 (on your VM). Can you please edit your question to clarify this?

Comment: @BrunoFaria - there are no OS-level firewall rules set by default when spinning up a new VM from the Azure OS images.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I have added new rule after posting this thread. It's strange, that 80 port working and 8000 not... I'll see if it actually reach it into OS level via tcpdump tomorrow...

Comment: Are you running CentOS?

Comment: Connections are reaching Ubuntu, but not the HTTP server itself. Very interesting.

Comment: 09:38:51.078342 IP my_ip > server_ip.8000: Flags [S], seq 2117346327, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0

Answer (score 0):

Azure use port forwarding (Endpoints) to connect to the VM, if you want to connect TO port 80 in the server FROM your computer using port 8000, you should add 8000 in the PUBLIC port and and 80 in the PRIVATE port. Normally they have the same value but for some reason we sometimes change it.

If for some reason, after you put the correct setting in azure endpoint (public 8000 and private 8000), you still can't connect, you should check your local computer firewall (either from windows or maybe antivirus) to allow port 8000

**Edit:**
Sometimes it will works after restarting the VM

Comment: don't forget to accept this as answer if it works so it will also help people that have the same problem